# Meteor Exception in delivering result of invoking server method

Tags: javascript, exception, asynchronous, meteor

Following code: I have a template where users can type in dates in a form and press a submit button. Now I want to check if this typed in date already exists in collection. When it exists an alert will popup. Simultaneously I want to check if the user is updating a existing date or create a new one.

Client.js

```
var currData = {_id: speakerDateArray[i]._id,
                        prID: prodIDVar,
                        title: currTitle,
                        start: speakerDateStartVar,
                        end: speakerDateEndVar};
if(allSpeakerDates.length == 0){
       Meteor.call('insertSpeakerDate', currData);
}
else {       
Meteor.call('delayedDateCompare', currData, function(err, result){
     var isDateExists = result; 
     console.log(err + ' ' +result);

     if(isDateExists === true) { 
         var isIdExists = Events.findOne({_id: speakerDateArray[i]._id});
         if(isIdExists !== undefined){ 
              console.log('ID vorhanden --> update');
              Meteor.call('updateSpeakerDate', currData);
         }
         else {
              alert('date already exist');
         }
      }
      else {
         var isIdExists = Events.findOne({_id: speakerDateArray[i]._id});
         if(isIdExists !== undefined){
              console.log('ID exists --> update');
              Meteor.call('updateSpeakerDate', currData);
          }
          else {
               console.log('ID not exist --> insert');
               Meteor.call('insertSpeakerDate', currData);
          }
       }
});
```

Server.js

```
function compareDates(delay, data, callback) {
        var tmpStart = moment(data.start).toDate(); 
        var tmpEnd = moment(data.end).toDate();   
        var allSpeakerDates = Events.find({categorie: 'speaker'}).fetch(); 
        var result;
        for(i=0; i<allSpeakerDates.length; i++) { 
            var exStart = moment(allSpeakerDates[i].start).toDate(); 
            var exEnd = moment(allSpeakerDates[i].end).toDate();     

            if (tmpStart > exStart && tmpEnd < exEnd) { 
                console.log('status 1');
                result = true;
            }
            else if(tmpStart < exStart && tmpEnd > exStart) { 
                console.log('status 2');
                result = true;
            }
            else if(tmpStart < exEnd && tmpEnd > exEnd) { 
                console.log('status 3');
                result = true;
            }
            else { 
                console.log('status 4');
                result = false;
            }
        }
        setTimeout(function() { 
            callback(null, result);
        }, delay);
    }
    var wrappedCompareDates = Async.wrap(compareDates);
```

Methods

```
Meteor.methods({
        'insertSpeakerDate': function(data){
            Events.insert({
                _id: data._id,
                prID: data.prID,
                title: data.title,
                start: data.start,
                end: data.end,
                color: '#009C95',
                categorie: 'speaker'
            });
        },
        'updateSpeakerDate': function(data) {
            console.log('Speakerdate updated: '+data._id);
            Events.update({_id: data._id}, {
                $set: {
                    title: data.title,
                    start: data.start,
                    end: data.end
                }
            });
        },
        'delayedDateCompare': function(data) {
            var response = wrappedCompareDates(1000, data); 
            return response;
        },
```

I get the error "Exception in delivering result of invoking 'delayedDateCompare'". I think this is due to the async-functionality of meteor but how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know the internal workings of Async.wrap but I believe you may need to remove the var declaration from wrappedCompareDates to make the method global.

Comment: Check the console on the server, it should be giving you a clear error of what happened on the server. Also you can debug your server code by running `meteor debug` on the console. Beyond that, your code has a host of problems: (1) you don't need nested server calls, that's slow. Just make a single method call and let the server handle all the logic returning an error if there's a dupe. (2) logic in `client.js` could be considerably simpler and faster, (3) `result` in your `for` loop in `server.js` will only be based on the last loop iteration, (4) consider `Collection.upsert()`